# How to group by key and value using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

I am using pig and this is part of the text I want to analyse:

```
SciTePress: 32    
Springer: 10    
Springer: 13    
Springer: 14    
Springer: 1571
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sort the text in an ascendant way. For instance, I want the output to look like this:

```
Springer: 1608  //( i.e. the sum of 10+13+14+1571)
SciTePress: 32
```

is there a way to achieve this using pig?

This is the output I am getting now:

```
Springer: 1571
SciTePress: 32  
Springer: 14  
Springer: 13    
Springer: 10
```

These are the commands I have used:

```
    WORDS = LOAD '../filename' using PigStorage(':') AS (title: chararray, count:int);
    grpd = GROUP WORDS BY count;
    sorted = order WORDS by count desc;
    top5 = limit sorted 5;
    dump top5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to group the data based on title and for each group we can call SUM function to get the sum.

**Input :**

```
SciTePress: 32    
Springer: 10    
Springer: 13    
Springer: 14    
Springer: 1571
```

**Pig Script :**

```
words = LOAD '/Users/muralirao/learning/pig/a.csv'  USING PigStorage(':') AS (title: chararray, title_count:int);
grp_by_title = GROUP  words BY title;
req_data = FOREACH grp_by_title GENERATE group AS title, SUM(words.title_count) AS total_count;
req_data_ordered = ORDER req_data BY total_count;
```

**Output : DUMP req_data_ordered**

```
(SciTePress,32)
(Springer,1608)
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the sum; however I also want the output sorted by count. I use the same command I use in my question but it does not sort this time:

**sorted = order WORDS by count desc;**

Any suggestion?

Comment: @OmarAlejandroChacinOrtega : Updated answer, have ordered by total_count field in ASC (default) order, if you need it in descending use DESC keyword. If you need to order by title use title field instead of total_count. Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#order-by